# howto parse required mutually exclusive argument in python C-api

Tags: python, c, arguments, mutual-exclusion

How does one go about to parse a group of required but mutually exclusive arguments using the python C-api?

E.g. given the function definition

```py
static PyObject* my_func(PyObject *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwargs)  {
   double a;          // first argument, required 
   double b=0, c=0;   // second argument, required but mutually exclusive, b is default keyword if no keyword is set
   char d[] = "...";  // third argument, optional

   // parse arguments
   ...
}
```

My idea here was to parse the input arguments twice, i.e. replacing `...` above with:

```py
   static const char *kwList1[] = {"a","b","c","d"};
   static const char *kwList2[] = {"a","b","d"};
   int ret;
   if (!(ret = PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args,kwargs,"d|dds",(char **)kwList1,&a,&b,&c,&d))) {
      ret = PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args,kwargs,"d|ds",(char **)kwList2,&a,&b,&d));
   }
   if (!ret) return NULL;

   // verify that one of, but not both, variables b and c are non-zero
   ...
```

However, the second call to `PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords()` returns 0 for valid input so I assume here that the variables `args` and `kwargs` have some attributes set by the first call to `PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords()` that causes the second call to fail (output python error is:  TypeError: a float is required).

I'm aware that the above could be solved using the `argparse` python module but would prefer a solution directly using the C-api. One idea here would be if it were possible to first copy of the input  `args` and `kwargs` into two new `PyObject` variables and use these in the second call to `PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords()`, however I can't find any api-function to do so (guess I also would need to know howto release the memory allocated for this).

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the issue were that the first call to `PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords()` set the error indicator which caused the second call to the function to fail. So the solution is to insert a call to `PyErr_Clear()` between the calls to `PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords()`. In summary, the following code performs the task

```py
static PyObject* my_func(PyObject *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwargs)  {
   double a;          // first argument, required 
   double b=0, c=0;   // second argument, required but mutually exclusive, b is default keyword if no keyword is set
   char d[] = "...";  // third argument, optional

   // parse arguments
   static const char *kwList1[] = {"a","b","c","d"};
   static const char *kwList2[] = {"a","b","d"};
   int ret;
   if (!(ret = PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args,kwargs,"d|dds",(char **)kwList1,&a,&b,&c,&d))) {
      PyErr_Clear();
      ret = PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args,kwargs,"d|ds",(char **)kwList2,&a,&b,&d));
   }
   if (!ret) return NULL;

   // verify that one of, but not both, variables b and c are non-zero
   if (b==0 && c==0) {
      PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError,"Required mutually exclusive arguments 'b' or 'c' (pos 2) not found (or input with value 0)");
      return NULL;
   } else if (b!=0 && c!=0) {
      PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError,"Use of multiple mutually exclusive required arguments 'b' and 'c' (pos 2)");
      return NULL;
   }

   ...

}
```

Then again this does not guard against the calling the function with both the arguments `b` and `c` given that one of them is 0 and the other not. However this is a minor problem.